# Multiple UpdateProgress Controls In TabContainer, Linked To Single UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, ajax

I have an UpdatePanel with a TabContainer in it.  Each TabPanel has a Gridview in it (code not included since it's not important), and I would like to have a different UpdateProgress controls located in each TabPanel. Please see my code below for an example of what I'm trying to do.

I know the standard approach is to locate the UpdateProgress control outside of the UpdatePanel, but I would like it/them to be located inside the UpdatePanel and TabContainer because I want the "Loading..." message to appear right on top of each of my GridViews. Currently the UpdateProgress control works on the first TabPanel (as indicated below in my code), but not on the second or any subsequent TabPanels.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updTest" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <ajax:TabContainer ID="conTest" runat="server">
        <ajax:TabPanel ID="pnlTest1" runat="server">
            <!--This UpdateProgress Control Does work-->
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updTest">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    Loading, please wait....
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
        </ajax:TabPanel>
        <ajax:TabPanel  ID="pnlTest1" runat="server">
            <!--This UpdateProgress Control Doesn't work. How can I fix it?-->
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updTest">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    Loading, please wait....
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
        </ajax:TabPanel>
    </ajax:TabContainer>
</ContentTemplate>
```

I'm open to another approach if the way I'm trying to accomplish this isn't the best way. Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is still only have one updateprogress but inside of your  put an updatepanel to change what your updateProgress shows.

something like this

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DynamicLayout="true">
<ProgressTemplate>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" >
        <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- put a label of something in here -->

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

hopefully this makes sense, I'm not the best at explaining sometimes.